# Alternative modelling approach for rod pendulum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

The classical way to derive the equation of motion of a pendulum with an isotropic rod is to study its motion with respect to its pivot point, that is, point $A$ in the following figure

[image: rod pendulum]

Then, given that the moment of inertia with respect to point $A$ is $I^{(A)} = \tfrac{1}{3}mL^2$, we have

\begin{align*}
&-mg\sin \theta \frac{L}{2} = \frac{1}{3}mL^2\ddot{\theta}
\\\Leftrightarrow&
\ \ddot{\theta} = -\frac{3g}{2L}\sin\theta.
\end{align*}

However, I would like to derive the equation of motion with respect to point $B$, i.e., using the moment of inertia $I^{(B)}$. I know I could use the parallel axis theorem to determine $I^{(A)}$ from $I^{(B)}$, but I would like to understand what might be wrong the the following derivation.

Consider the following forces:

[image: rod pendulum - alternative approach]

The forces shown in red are the decomposition of the reaction that corresponds to the weight of the rod (the reaction that the ceiling exerts on the pendulum). The moment of inertia wrt of point $B$ is $I^{(B)} = \tfrac{1}{12}mL^2$ and the total torque with respect to point $B$ is $T^{(B)} = -mg\sin\theta \tfrac{L}{2}$, but then we get

\begin{align*}
&-mg\sin \theta \frac{L}{2} = \frac{1}{12}mL^2\ddot{\theta}
\\\Leftrightarrow&
\ \ddot{\theta} = -\frac{6g}{L}\sin\theta.
\end{align*}

What's missing or wrong about the second approach that accounts for this difference?

Comment: Seriously?! I got a down-vote on my **first** question, without a comment?! This doesn't seem to foster a very constructive discourse, does it?

Comment: Downvoters are encouraged but not required to comment with their reasoning and suggestions for improvement. After all, that's the reason why we have anonymous vote buttons on this website. I suspect the initial downvote (which wasn't cast by me, in fact I thought the question was alright and upvoted) was because your question body didn't contain an actual question, but just two derivations that are in conflict with each other, which is why I put in the edit. Hopefully I interpreted your intention right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error in the second approach, I believe, is that the "reaction" force at the hinge is not simply equal and opposite to the weight of the rod. The center of mass of the rod is in circular motion and has a tangential acceleration. Thus the forces perpendicular to the rod should not be cancel each other, but should provide this tangential acceleration. Thus the perpendicular hinge force (call it $N_\perp$) should satisfy both
$$
N_\perp \left(\frac{L}{2}\right) = \frac{1}{12} m L^2 \ddot{\theta}
$$
and
$$
mg\sin\theta -N_\perp = m \left(\frac{L}{2}\right) \ddot{\theta}
$$
Combining these equations will get you the same equation of motion as the first approach.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Could you explain what is the meaning of the term $(L/2)\ddot{\theta}$ in the second equation. I guess the second equation is Newton's second law of motion along the axis that is perpendicular to the rod (the tangential direction). Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: Yes, it is indeed Newton's second law. The right hand side is the acceleration along the tangential direction. The velocity in this direction is $(L/2)\dot{\theta}$, because the radius of the motion is $L/2$, so taking another derivative gives $(L/2)\ddot{\theta}$. Alternatively we can note that since there is no radial motion, the tangential acceleration is just equal to the angular acceleration times the radius.